# Is there an iphone url scheme to start a web app in standalone mode from a link

Tags: iphone, web-applications, iphone-standalone-web-app

What I'm trying to do is this:

- I've got a web app the user can choose to add to the homescreen and run in standalone mode.
- Sometimes the server side of the app sends SMS'es to the user to notify the user of 
  significant events. The SMS contains an URI to the app page of the event.
- If the user has added the application to homescreen I would like to launch the app in 
  standalone mode

Is there a way to achieve this?

**EDIT**

From what I've found so far iOS does not implement a url scheme for launching browser based (ie. web apps) in standalone mode. ... But apple should though :) Apple implements parsing of urls to youtube.com and redirects them to the video app.

If they store the URL to the app placed on the home screen it would be a simple task to redirect links to that app.

Comment: Only for the record, since it isn't supported in iOS, but the Android 'intent' functionality is similar to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iOS does not implement a url scheme for launching browser based (ie. web apps) in standalone mode. ... But apple should though :) Apple implements parsing of urls to youtube.com and redirects them to the video app.

If they store the URL to the app placed on the home screen it would be a simple task to redirect links to that app.

Answer (score 1):

not from an SMS I don't think - but you could look at push notifications which can be sent from your server. I haven't used them yet, but the way I understand it you can send a notification from your server and link it to the app.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

sorry, thats probably a better link

Comment: Seems like it is not possible to push to a web app though. The app needs to be in the app store for it to get a SSL key to access apples push gateway.

Comment: ah sorry - I didn't understand what you meant by web app - you could make a hybrid application which you could put into the app store?